# Flask - Working outside application context

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to instantiate an object against a class right when I instantiate the flask application, however am receiving an error regarding working outside the flask application context. Below is my current code and any help would be appreciated. I am waiting to bring in that module and call an object against it until after the 'create_app' has successfully run, yet still not able to identify the root cause of my issue.

```
from app import create_app

import os

app = create_app()

# instantiate the object
from app.main.dpt_manager import DPTManager

obj = DPTManager() # here is where I am instantiating the object I would like


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

App init:

```
from flask_api import FlaskAPI

from app.config import Config


def create_app():
    """Instantiates and initialize the Flask application"""
    app = FlaskAPI(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    from app.api.casify_service.authorization import auth
    from app.api.casify_service.predict import predict

    app.register_blueprint(auth)
    app.register_blueprint(predict)

    return app
```

Config file:

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv


class Config:
    """Base configuration."""

    dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), ".env")
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

    ldaps_config = dict()
    API_VERSION = "1.0.0"

    # auth related key / values
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
    TOKEN_EXPIRE_HOURS = 24
```

DPTManager class:

```
from flask import current_app


class DPTManager:

    def __init__(self):
        token_age_h = current_app.config.get("TOKEN_EXPIRE_HOURS") # failure occurs here
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aclinton/Documents/projects/casify_autoescalation/casify/casify-service/run.py", line 10, in <module>
    dpt_manager = DPTManager()
  File "/Users/aclinton/Documents/projects/casify_autoescalation/casify/casify-service/app/main/dpt_manager.py", line 21, in __init__
    token_age_h = current_app.config.get("TOKEN_EXPIRE_HOURS")
  File "/Users/aclinton/Documents/environments/casify-service/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/aclinton/Documents/environments/casify-service/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/aclinton/Documents/environments/casify-service/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

Comment: did you try to send it as argument `DPTManager(app)` ?

Comment: did you try using with app.app_context(): obj = DPTManager()

Comment: @charchit are you suggesting I replace "obj = DPTManager() # here is where I am instantiating the object I would like" with what you are suggesting? Because this does work, however how would I be able to access that object from other modules in this manner?

Comment: ya you are still instantiating the object I just added with app.app_context(): #instantiate the object. if you are not able to understand in comments, I can write a answer to make it clear

Comment: @charchit Maybe I am going about this in an inefficient way. My goal is to instantiate this object at the flask app instantiation and use this object across several modules in the code. Is this the best way?

Comment: you can import the module and object and can use it without `with app.app_context():` in other files. maybe I don''t understand you. is this what you asking?

Comment: @charchit gotcha thanks! I believe you answered my question.